# %d by python and addition ValueError: unsupported format character 'O' (0x4f) at index 2

Tags: python, addition

i wrote a small function to do this job

```
x = 'INV-%05d'
m = x %(100+1)
```

i should have m = `INV-0101`

but i receive this error

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'O' (0x4f) at index 2
```

this works without any problem, but i want to use an external variable

```
m = INV-%05d %(100+1)
```

-> m = `INV-0101`

because the original value should come from a saved variable

Comment: First off, m will be INV-00101 since you are padding up to 5 digits with 0's.  Second, where are you getting your external variable in this example?

Comment: I don't think that error message is from running that code.  Can you double-check that you gave us all the relevant details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x4f`, as reported in the error message, is the ASCII value for the capital letter O. It looks like you have made a typographical error, and put an O in when you want a zero.

Comment: +1 and now we know the reason why the hex value is also added to the error message